# Include Directory to CSV File Cmake

Tags: c, csv, cmake, include-path

I am attempting to use cmake to build my visual studio 2017 project. The program, written in C, parses a csv file. The issue is the file is in a different folder from the c file. How would I set it so I can use fopen() just by giving it the name of the file rather than the path?

This is the layout of my program:

```
|--include
|   |--header_files.h
|--src
|   |--util
|   |   |--app_util.c
|   |   |--other_files.c
|   |--main
|   |   |--app.c
|--userdata
|   |--fitness_cases.csv
|--CMakeLists.txt
```

The goal is to be able to call fopen("fitness_cases.csv") in app_util.c, which I think should be done by including the directory /userdata in the CMakeLists.txt file. How would I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, but I ended up doing something slightly different than what my question asked. I came up with a solution that automatically detects the path of the file and includes it as a macro in a header file.

The way I did it was by creating a CMakeLists.txt file in the include folder. I then had it configure a header file which contained a macro to the path by searching for the csv file is userdata. Then I included the new CMakeLists.txt in the main one.

This was the setup my program has:

```
|--include
|   |--header_files.h
|   |--CMakeLists.txt
|   |--csv_file.h.in
|--src
|   |--util
|   |   |--app_util.c
|   |   |--other_files.c
|   |--main
|   |   |--app.c
|--userdata
|   |--fitness_cases.csv
|--CMakeLists.txt
```

The CMakeLists.txt file in the include folder looks like this:

```
#Search for csv file
file(GLOB CSV_DIR "data/*.csv" )

# configure the header.
set(DIR_STRING "${CSV_DIR}")
configure_file("include/params.h.in" "include/params.h")

# Includes the new header
include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR})
```

csv_file.h.in is just a single line:

```
#cmakedefine CSV_DIR "@DIR_STRING@"
```

Then I added this to the main CMakeLists.txt:

```
include("${DIR}/include/CMakeLists.txt")
```

By using doing this, after building it with CMake I can use the variable CSV_DIR anywhere in the program.